# Run AWS Lambda function locally with Docker & Hot Reload in monorepo environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Demo of the application use case is here for your convenience: https://github.com/tal-rofe/demo-lambda

---

I set up a monorepo environment, where I simply have `apps` folder with  2 applications, `frontend` and `pixel-api`.

I want to run these **both** locally with hot reload. Meaning- whenever I modify each project's source code, the artifacts refreshes. For example I run the frontend application with NextJS so it is easily supported by running `next dev` inside the docker container and using Bind Mount to the source code on host machine.

Problem is I try to do the same with Lambda function. AWS support the `sam local start-api` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html) command which is helpful, but I rather not install the `sam` CLI to a developer machine.

So my intention is to run the SAM CLI inside Docker.

I found this comment describing how to do so: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/55#issuecomment-1717711860
And also this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/55#issuecomment-1717819156

I copied the code and tried to adjust it to my project but didn't go well.

Root/docker-compose.dev.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    pixel-api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.pixel-api-dev
        command: sam local start-api -t "${PWD}/apps/pixel-api/template.yaml" -v "${PWD}/.aws-sam/build" --host=0.0.0.0 --container-host=host.docker.internal --container-host-interface=127.0.0.1
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
            - ${PWD}:${PWD}:ro
            - /dashboard/apps/pixel-api/node_modules
            - /dashboard/node_modules
        environment:
            SAM_CLI_TELEMETRY: 0
            SAM_CLI_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: 30
            sam_local_environment: 'true'

    frontend:
        container_name: frontend
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.frontend-dev
        env_file:
            - ./apps/frontend/envs/.env.development
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        restart: always
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./apps/frontend/src
              target: /dashboard/apps/frontend/src
            - /dashboard/apps/frontend/node_modules

networks:
    dashboard_network:
        driver: bridge
```

**The "frontend" service works as intended and succeeds.**

Root/apps/pixel-api/template.yaml:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: SAM template for running locally API Gateway & Lambda function for Pixel API function

Globals:
    Api:
        Cors:
            AllowMethods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
            AllowHeaders: "'content-type','x-api-key','x-amz-security-token','authorization','x-amz-user-agent','x-amz-date'"
            AllowOrigin: "'*'"
            AllowCredentials: "'*'"

Resources:
    AwsApiGateway:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
        Properties:
            Name: AWS API Gateway - Pixel API
            StageName: development

    MyLambdaFunction:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
            Runtime: nodejs20.x
            Handler: index.handler
            CodeUri: build
            Timeout: 30
            Description: 'Pixel API Lambda function'
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    sam_local_environment: 'true'
            Events:
                Api:
                    Type: HttpApi
                    Properties:
                        ApiId: !Ref AwsApiGateway
                        Path: /
                        Method: POST
```

I also have "Root/apps/pixel-api/build/index.js` file as for the Lambda function NodeJS function.

I also have the Dockerfile for the pixel-api service:

Root/docker/Dockerfile.pixel-api-dev:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/docker

ENV PIP_BREAK_SYSTEM_PACKAGES 1

RUN apk update && \
    apk add gcc py-pip python3-dev libffi-dev musl-dev && \
    pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && \
    pip install --upgrade aws-sam-cli

WORKDIR /var/opt

ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I run the services using `docker-compose up -d`, both services succeeds. But when I run `curl -X POST http://localhost:3000` - invoking the Lambda function fails:

```
Mounting MyLambdaFunction at http://0.0.0.0:3000/ [POST]
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. If you used sam build before running local commands, you will need to re-run sam build for the changes to be picked up. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2024-03-20 07:24:30 WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
 * Running on http://172.20.0.2:3000
2024-03-20 07:24:30 Press CTRL+C to quit
Invoking index.handler (nodejs20.x)
Local image was not found.
Removing rapid images for repo public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs20.x
Building image..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Using local image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20-rapid-x86_64.

Mounting /MY_MACHINE_PATH/dashboard/.aws-sam/build/build as /var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container
START RequestId: 3e76c0ee-26bb-4250-983c-f60252289641 Version: $LATEST
2024-03-20T07:25:35.076Z        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'index'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"]}
20 Mar 2024 07:25:35,212 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=
20 Mar 2024 07:25:35,216 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=33a8293f-9315-4d2a-808f-265f5620f20f
20 Mar 2024 07:25:35,218 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke DONE failed: Sandbox.Failure

2024-03-20 07:25:36 192.168.65.1 - - [20/Mar/2024 07:25:36] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

**My questions:**

1. Note that I didn't run `sam build` at all, I don't even have `sam` CLI on my host machine. **If I need to do so**, how can I do it inside the Docker?
2. After trying to use `nodejs20.x` version for my function, as you can see from the logs I attached:

```
Local image was not found.
Removing rapid images for repo public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs20.x
Building image..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Using local image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20-rapid-x86_64.
```

So, OK, no image, but it runs after first request to lambda fired. Is there a way to do it ahead of time, on Dockerfile.pixel-api-dev? So first request won't need to wait the image to download...

3. **And of-course the main question - why did it fail to find my Lambda function?**
4. Also, how can I enable hot reload for this lambda function so every time I modify the `Root/apps/pixel-api/build/index.js` file, the lambda functions refreshes on `localhost:3000`? Note that comment from the logs I attached:

```
You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions,
changes will be reflected instantly/automatically.
If you used sam build before running local commands, you will need to re-run sam build for the changes to be picked up
```

Again, I don't want to use `sam` CLI on my host machine, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution but rather migration solution to other framework. As I don't mind the underlying framework used to test my Lambda function code, this solution is good for me.

I migrated the development framework to use the [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) instead. Then I just created this `serverless.yaml` file:

```yaml
org: kynesis
app: pixel-api
console: true
service: pixel-http-api
frameworkVersion: '3'
configValidationMode: error

provider:
    name: aws
    httpApi:
        cors:
            allowedOrigins:
                - '*'
            allowedHeaders:
                - Content-Type
            allowedMethods:
                - POST
            allowCredentials: false

custom:
    serverless-offline:
        # * https://forum.serverless.com/t/possible-to-run-serverless-in-a-docker-container/5764/4
        host: 0.0.0.0

plugins:
    - serverless-offline

functions:
    pixel-api:
        name: pixel-api
        runtime: nodejs20.x
        handler: ./build/index.handler
        events:
            - httpApi:
                  path: /
                  method: POST
```

modified my docker compose file to:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    pixel-api:
        container_name: pixel-api
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.pixel-api-dev
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        restart: always
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./apps/pixel-api/src
              target: /dashboard/apps/pixel-api/src
            - /dashboard/apps/pixel-api/node_modules
            - /dashboard/node_modules

    frontend:
        container_name: frontend
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.frontend-dev
        env_file:
            - ./apps/frontend/envs/.env.development
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        restart: always
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./apps/frontend/src
              target: /dashboard/apps/frontend/src
            - /dashboard/apps/frontend/node_modules
            - /dashboard/node_modules

networks:
    dashboard_network:
        driver: bridge
```

modified my Dockerfile to

```
FROM node:20.11.1

RUN npm i -g pnpm@8.15.4

WORKDIR /dashboard

COPY ./package.json ./pnpm-workspace.yaml ./.npmrc ./
COPY ./apps/pixel-api/package.json ./apps/pixel-api/

RUN pnpm i -w
RUN pnpm --filter pixel-api i

COPY ./tsconfig.base.json ./nx.json ./
COPY ./apps/pixel-api/ ./apps/pixel-api/

CMD ["pnpm", "exec", "nx", "start:dev", "blabla"]
```

Then I also configured `nodemon.json` file to rebuild my Lambda code and restart the serverless framework server:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nodemon.json",
    "watch": ["./src", "./serverless.yaml"],
    "ext": "ts,json",
    "exec": "node ./esbuild.js && sls offline --httpPort 3000"
}
```